# Access text variable of NSTextField?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I want to access the text variable of NSTextField ?

I'v tried this. But it's not working.

```
name = textfield.text
```

Error: "Value of type 'NSTextField' has no member 'text'"

Comment: name = textfield.stringvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you confusing it with `UITextField` on iOS? The corresponding property on Mac OS X is `stringValue`

```
name = textfield.stringValue
```